# Redirect Google Oauth2.0 LOCALHOST:9696/Callback On live Tomcat Server

Tags: spring, tomcat, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I'm working on implementing Google drive API v3 in java spring boot. The application works fine on my local machine. I deployed the application in TOMCAT which is running on our UAT server for testing. I am following the procedure to Authorize my Google Drive API i got the consent window. I selected all the permissions that i require to access API and clicked allow button but right after that it redirected me to https://localhost:9696/callback URL which gives me page not found. I am stuck till here. do i need to provide my domain instead of default localhost has callback URL?

````
```
private static Credential getCredentials(final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT) throws IOException {
        // Load client secrets.
        InputStream in = GoogleDriveService.class.getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
        if (in == null) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Resource not found: " + CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
        }
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

        // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY,
                clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                        .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))
                        .setAccessType("offline").build();
        LocalServerReceiver receiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(9696).build();
        return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver).authorize("user");
    }
````

```
Implementation Ref. API Doc:- 
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/java?hl=en&authuser=2
```

Comment: What is the issue exactly?  Please edit your question and include [example]

Comment: Please **EDIT** your question and include your code not put it in a comment.

Comment: you have created an installed application your code should be able to  handle the response from the authentication server.  You understand that by creating an installed application the consent window is going to open on the server right.